# PHP cUrl - post data doesn't go through proxy

Tags: php, curl, authentication, proxy

I use this code to login to remote server. Evrything working fine when I don't use proxy. But with proxy it doesn't.

Here is code:

```
  $ch = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "cookie.txt");
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "cookie.txt");
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 20);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);


  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);

  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $ref_url);


  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPPROXYTUNNEL, TRUE); 
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, $proxy.':'.$port);
  ob_start();

  return curl_exec ($ch); // execute the curl command
  ob_end_clean();
  curl_close ($ch);
  unset($ch);
```

I try to disable CURLOPT_HTTPPROXYTUNNEL but it didn't help.

So, without proxy I can login fine.
With proxy not.
Proxy is good ad working.

Comment: This won't fix the problem directly, but a) because you have set `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` the output buffering is pointless, get rid of the `ob_start()`/`ob_end_clean()` calls, and b) you are attempting to run code after a `return` statement - this will NEVER be executed, you need to catch the return data in a variable, then call `curl_close()`, then return the data. I'm guessing since you have a `return` call this is in a function, so the `unset()` call is unnecessary - the handle will be destroyed when you leave the scope of the function.

Comment: What do you get if your replace the `return` call with `echo` - i.e. what is the output of the `curl_exec()`? You will need to remove the output buffering to see this...

Comment: This is just function that I call several times when navigating site where I login and scrape some data. In first run I check proxy, then login, then navigate inside site...but all that is working fine when I don't use proxy...so code is fine...but when using proxy then after login page I get again login page, like it doesn't send post data to login page.

Answer (score 0):

What's the proxy error you get using the code you posted? Does the proxy need authentication?

Comment: I don't get any error. Proxy is working fine. In first call I check is proxy working. I think it just don't send post data when using proxy.

Comment: @ CodeCaster : do u have skype ?

Comment: CURL will send post data over a proxy. What is the data you get from CURL when you issue the request? Try using `error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);` before calling `curl_exec()`;. And yes, I do have skype, support rates start at $40 a quarter.

Answer (score 0):

I was having a same problem , the code works fine without the proxy but with it its returning nothing 
, I have done some debugging and found out that actually on most of the servers only the port 80 is allowed , and many of the proxies we use connect through another port

- You can unblock the port no for which you have maximum proxies
- You can filter the list with only port 80 proxies

**Note** : Also only use port http, https and socks4 proxies , socks5 proxies runs on udp not on tcp/ip